# Vertically align UIImageView added as rightView of textfield with the text of skyfloatinglabeltextfield

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, rightview, skyfloatinglabeltextfield

I have added a checkmarkImageView as rightview of a [skyfloatinglabeltextfield](https://github.com/Skyscanner/SkyFloatingLabelTextField) as follows:

```
let checkmark = UIImage(named: "checkmark") 
checkmarkImageView = UIImageView(image: checkmark)
checkmarkImageView?.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 20.0, height: 20.0)
textfield?.rightView = checkmarkImageView
textfield?.rightViewMode = .always
editView.addSubview(textfield!)
```

It is not aligning vertically centre with the text of the textfield. How do I achieve that?
[image: It is not aligning vertically centre with the text of the textfield.]

Comment: To check this issue, set background colour to image view and text field.

Comment: Try to set the height of the UIImageView frame to the same height as the TextField

Comment: Check what is frame you are getting for `checkmarkImageView` in UI debugger.

Comment: Also check for the image, if the padding for PNG image is incorrect, then vertically aligning it will also not work.

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys. Let me try/check all those suggestions and get back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change the `frame.offsetBy`, I used textfield `Border Style` as `Plain`

```
    let rightVie = UIView()
    rightVie.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

   checkmarkImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "checkmark")) // use your imageView
  //  checkmarkImageView?.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 20.0, height: 20.0)
   checkmarkImageView.frame = checkmarkImageView.frame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: -1 + textfield.titleHeight()/2)
    rightVie.frame = checkmarkImageView.frame
    rightVie.addSubview(checkmarkImageView)
    //use your textfield name
    textfield?.rightView = rightVie
    textfield?.rightViewMode = .always
```

**output**

[image]

Comment: I tried this but unfortunately didn't work for me Anbu. I couldn't see any difference. May be it is because I am using SkyFloatingTextfield and frame of it is larger than just text+bottom line.

Comment: can you modify your answer by changing dy to (-1 + textfield.titleHeight()/2). SkyFloatingLabelTextField is a custom textfield with a title added. So, we need to bring down the checkmark by an amount equal to half the height of the top title.

Comment: This works, hence asked you to do the modification. Will accept the answer but I have used textfield as instance name, so can you update the answer with the same instance names (also for checkmarkImageView) as in the questions so that it is straight away helpful for someone having the same issue?

Comment: checkmarkImageView instead of getCheckmark as well please.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Please change the variable name on rhs. Many thanks Anbu.
   checkmarkImageView.frame = getCheckmarkImageView.frame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: -1 + textfield.titleHeight()/2)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171316/discussion-between-josh-and-anbu-karthik).

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the frame of `checkmarkImageView` to:

```
checkmarkImageView?.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 20.0, height: textfield.bounds.height)
```

And please add a screenshot of the frames you are getting from the UI debugger.

**Edit:**

```
checkmarkImageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
```

Edit-2:

To get the height of the text, use:

```
let textHeight = text.size(withAttributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.openSansBold(size: 10)]).height
```

Add the attributes according to your requirement.

Let me know if you still face any issues.

Comment: if you change the height , then checkmarkImageView? is not shows as squre

Comment: Set the contentMode of `checkmarkImageView` to `AspectFit`.

Comment: That will not work PGDev, my textfield starts all the way from nombre (title) to bottom line. This is SkyFloatingTextField. I want my image to be only as big as text and vertically align it with text.

Comment: Then in that case, you need to calculate the height of the text and set the `checkmarkImageView's` origin - y to `height/2`. You have to customize it accordingly.

Comment: I thought of that way before using textfield.rightView. How to find the height of text inside textfield?

Comment: what's text? (textfield.text?). Fortunately, SkyfloatingLabelTextField has getTextHeight() method. Now I am in a fix. Both the answers helped me to the right answer.

Comment: Sure. Happy coding..:)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171314/discussion-between-josh-and-pgdev).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use that function:

```
func setupNavUI() {
    let addressTextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: self.navigationItem.titleView?.frame.width ?? 100.0, height: 50.0))
    addressTextField.rightViewMode = .always
    let icon = FAKFontAwesome.sortDownIcon(withSize: 20.0)
    icon?.setAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.lightGray])
    let image = icon?.image(with: CGSize(width: 20.0, height: 20.0))
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 20.0, height: 20.0))
    imageView.image = image
    let rightView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20.0, height: 26.0))
    rightView.addSubview(imageView)
    addressTextField.rightView = rightView
    addressTextField.placeholder = "Buscar una dirección"
    self.navigationItem.titleView = addressTextField
}
```

Best Regards